# unable to view Silverlight control

Tags: silverlight, controls

I have created a simple silverlight control. When I view the control in browser, it asks me to install Silverlight (whereas it is already there on my machine). and when I still go ahead and install silverlight, it says Cannot install, same version of Silverlight already exists.
Whats wrong??

Thanks!!

EDIT: Uninstalled and reinstalled it.. and it worked.. but still wondering what must be the issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this issue a few months back.  It has something to do with the registry.  I had to use subinacl along with a script to fix this issue.  I would recommand uninstall and reinstall the latest silverlight, and then use subinacl and apply the following in a windows batch file:

```
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl /grant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl /grant=users=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl /grant=system=f

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl\CLSID /grant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl\CLSID /grant=users=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl\CLSID /grant=system=f

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.2.0 /grant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.2.0 /grant=users=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.2.0 /grant=system=f 

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.3.0 /grant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.3.0 /grant=users=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.3.0 /grant=system=f

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.4.0 /grant=administrators=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.4.0 /grant=users=f 
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AgControl.AgControl.4.0 /grant=system=f

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0 /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0 /grant=users=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.vbproj.9.0 /grant=system=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0 /grant=administrators=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0 /grant=users=f
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualStudio.csproj.9.0 /grant=system=f
```

you can download subinacl here [Subinacl](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e8ba3e56-d8fe-4a91-93cf-ed6985e3927b&displaylang=en)

Comment: I had already uninstalled and installed the latest version (which solved my issue). I also did what you asked using subinacl.. so this means this issue will not reappear??

Comment: is it working now?  i have not yet had a client come back with similar issue after the fix.  however, issue might arise when you uninstall and reinstall silverlight.

Comment: my issue was resolved earlier, however, markign this as answer as it answers "why" part of the question!

Comment: in my experience, if i remember correctly, AgControl.AgControl in the registry had jacked up permissions, and thus, unaccessible until permission was granted VIA subinacl.